# Using external "live" javascript in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate with stripe in my angular frontend application.

From the stripe documentaion: *"Always load Stripe.js directly from https://js.stripe.com. You can’t include it in a bundle or self-host it."*

I have added the script in head tag of my index, and I see that it is loaded correctly.
`<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>`

But when trying to use it in the ts code:

```
declare var stripe: any;
```

and:

```
  stripe
    .redirectToCheckout({
      sessionId: this.sessionId
    })
    .then(x => {
      console.log(x);
    });
```

This results in "stripe is not defined".

Is there a solution here?

Preferably I dont want to load the javascript file before I need it but that is maybe another question, or maybe the solution for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did will not work - you're declaring the `stripe` variable yourself, which will not work.

The good news is - you misunderstood the docs. If you'll take a look at their [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/js) (**bold** added by me):

> We also provide an npm package that **makes it easier to load** and use Stripe.js as a module. For more information, check out the project on GitHub.

What this means is that they have an npm package that will load the script from their page (i.e. https://js.stripe.com/v3/) and serve it to you in a nice TypeScript wrapper. So, by using THEIR npm module, you're definitely PCI compliant.

You should be good by following the guide on their on the [package git page](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js).